# Como puedo pasar elementos li de una lista a otra que funcione en ambos sentidos

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo una lista y necesito que al hacer clic sobre uno de los li pase ese elemento a la otra lista, debe de funcionar en ambos sentidos.

Según lo consultado lo puedo hacer mediante appendTo pero en este momento me está pasando la lista completa a la otra lista (se desaparece por completo) y no es  eso lo que necesito hacer.

```
----------
app.js
----------
// escribe tu código acá
$(document).ready(function(){   
   // aqui definimos el evento sobre los li 
   $('.todo').on('click', 'li', function(){
    // Mover elemento li de todo a done     
       $('.todo').appendTo('.done');
   });
}); 


----------
index.html
----------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tareas terminadas</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <h3>Por hacer:</h3>
      <ul class="todo">
        <li>Sacar la ropa</li>
        <li>Lavar los platos</li>
        <li>Hacer la cama</li>
        <li>Leer un rato</li>
        <li>Terminar este reto</li>
        <li>Sacar al perro</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
      <h3>Hecho:</h3>
      <ul class="done">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
   <!-- incluye acá jQuery y crea la referencia a app.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


----------
style.css
----------
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.done li {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad estabas muy muy cerca de lograrlo, solo debías cambiar el selector con el cual estabas moviendo el elemento al otro listado.

Te dejo el código funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.todo').on('click', 'li', function(){    
       $(this).appendTo('.done');
    });

    $('.done').on('click', 'li', function(){    
       $(this).appendTo('.todo');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 330px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #f5f5f2;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li {
  color: #66665D;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBD3;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.done li {
  color: #ABABA4;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list">
  <h3>Por hacer:</h3>
  <ul class="todo">
    <li>Sacar la ropa</li>
    <li>Lavar los platos</li>
    <li>Hacer la cama</li>
    <li>Leer un rato</li>
    <li>Terminar este reto</li>
    <li>Sacar al perro</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <h3>Hecho:</h3>
  <ul class="done">
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Al cambiar `$(".todo").appendTo('.done');` por `$(this).appendTo('.done');` estás haciendo referencia al `<li>` al cual le acabas de dar click, evitando así que todo el `<ul>` completo se añadiera a la segunda lista.